# dailyLimitExceededUnreg error on authenticated download requests for abusive files

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm getting the following error when trying to download files from my Google Drive folder using JavaScript.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

I'm using googleapis library, version v3 with OAuth2 authorization.
My function downloads most of the files correctly but throws an error on some specific ones each time I run it.
The library itself prints cannotDownloadAbusiveFile error in the console but the response link shows the error above.

The acknowledgeAbuse flag is set to true. The files that this method refuses to download can't be downloaded from the web-interface either because of the viruses.
I tried changing the Google Drive user in OAuth2 to the creator of the files (it was just someone who has access before), it didn't fix anything.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.

Means there is an issue with your authorization at some point you are sending a request with either a missing access token or an expired one.

As for cannotDownloadAbusiveFile you can set a flag in your request it should be one of the optional parameter's.  `acknowledgeAbuse='true'` this will allow you to download files that Google has denoted as unsafe.  If it contains malware though from what i recall only the owner can download that.